# Symfony 3, include a css library with some dependencies

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

From a personal symfony 3 project, I want use the font-awesome library. In the config.yml file I added an asset like that :

```
    awesomefont_css:
        inputs:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/library/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
```

I call the asset from my index.php page :

```
{% stylesheets output="stylesheet.css"
'@bootstrap_css'
'@awesomefont_css'
"@style_css"
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I cleared caches (via php bin/console cache:clear) but when I load my php page, I get the errors :

[image]

I understood the library font-awesome need use some another files. My question is : how can/must I add properly theses anothers files in a symfony 3 ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have the font files (.woff, .woff2, .tff, etc) in the /web/fonts/ directory from the download? http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip

Comment: no, my fonts files are in the "font awesome" directory : '/var/www/kali/web/library/font-awesome/fonts' and the path using by the "font awesome" css file is '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff' '../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2' ...

Comment: Have you run the `assets:install` command?

Comment: this command install ressources of bundles. I don't use any bundle here

Answer (score 0):

I add samples symbolic links from mywebsite/web/library/font-awesome/fonts/* to mywebsite/web/fonts . I don't know if there is a better solution but I don't find another and that work

Comment: Please could you show me the exact code you used in your template to import those font-awesome ressources ? Did you import them with a <link href="stylesheet" type="text/css"> tag ?

Comment: In my template, I have only the '{% stylesheets ... %}' code. Then when I load my page, the default 'font awesome' css loaded searches its ressources (.woff , .woff2, ..., files) in '../fonts/' directory (the directory used by default by the 'font awesome' library). Then, the 'font awesome' css loaded searches its ressources in '/var/www/mywebsite/web/fonts'. Thanks to my symbolic links I added, the files in '/var/www/mywebsite/web/fonts' are symbolics links to '/var/www/mywebsite/web/library/font-awesome/fonts'. (symbolics links created via the linux command 'ln -s')

Answer (score 0):

I included `fortawesome/font-awesome` via composer.

Then, you have to add additional entries to your config.yml:

```
        fontawesome_css:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
            filters: [cssrewrite]
        font-awesome-otf:
            inputs: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/fonts/FontAwesome.otf'
            output: 'fonts/FontAwesome.otf'
        font-awesome-eot:
            inputs: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot'
            output: 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot'
        font-awesome-svg:
            inputs: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg'
            output: 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg'
        font-awesome-ttf:
            inputs: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf'
            output: 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf'
        font-awesome-woff:
            inputs: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff'
            output: 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff'
        font-awesome-woff2:
            inputs: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/fortawesome/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2'
            output: 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2'
```

then only include the `fontawesome_css` (as you did already):

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets '@bootstrap_css' '@fontawesome_css' '@custom_css' %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
        {% endstylesheets %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Finally, run

```
bin/console assetic:dump
```

and you're done! It is *not* necessary to mention the font files in your template, they are copied automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I should add that the [webpack/encore](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend.html) package is new and much better in my opinion! It replaces assetic.

You can also easily customize your bootstrap theme on the fly with this tool.

Answer (score 0):

working in symfony 3 / 4 / 5 / 6

workaround for it is to include font css file in twig in `<style> </style>` tag

```
    /* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Two Tone';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('material/material.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

than change it into

```
   /* fallback */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons Two Tone';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url({{ asset('dashboard/assets/fonts/material/material.woff2') }}) format('woff2');
}
```

where material.css file is

```
public/dashboard/assets/fonts/material.css
```

and file contains

```
    [![@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Two Tone';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('material/material.woff2') format('woff2');
}

.material-icons-two-tone {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Two Tone';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}]
```

[image: list of files in fonts directory]